# Call more than one function in match arm in Rust

Tags: rust, match

I currently have a match statement in the form of

```
match ball.side {
    Side::Left => x(), 
    Side::Right => y(), 
}
```

But what I would need is something along the lines of

```
match ball.side {
    Side::Left => x(),a(), 
    Side::Right => y(), b(), 
}
```

And of course this does not compile, but how could I make this kind of sequence work? 
I know I could also just work with an *if*-statement but I am curious how this can exactly be solved with match.

Comment: https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch18-03-pattern-syntax.html - note the latter forms that take a block.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A sequence of statements in a block:

```rust
match ball.side {
    Side::Left => {
        x();
        a();
    }
    Side::Right => {
        y();
        b();
    }
}
```

Note that the right side of a `match` arm must be an *expression*, and that [blocks are expressions](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/expressions/block-expr.html) (which can produce a value) in Rust.